# Update columns for every loop of a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dynamic, while-loop

Given this data frame:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'STORE': ['Store_1', 'Store_1', 'Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_2', 'Store_2'],
              'ITEM': ['oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges'],
               'AVAILABLE': [5, 5, 5, 13, 13, 13],
              'USER': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '5', '4'],
               'NEED': [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]})
    df
```

[image: dataframe]

Every store delivers to a few of its covered users. How do I create a loop that the store with available oranges delivers 1 orange to its covered user with the most need? And every item/orange delivered the need for that user id will deduct 1, and the available for that store will also deduct 1.

The tricky part is both Store 1 and Store 2 have User 1 so when store 1 delivers 1 - need should also be deducted from that same user id.

**Output should look something like:**

[image]

In the output you see how the store 2 did not deliver anymore to User 1 because store 1 already did so the need was already fulfilled. This is the code that I have so far and I've been stuck:

```
group = df.groupby(['STORE','ITEM'])

df["DELIVER"]  = 0

for name, group in a_group:
    while ((df['AVAILABLE'] > 0) & df['NEED'] != 0).any():
        max_idx = df.groupby(['STORE', 'ITEM'])['NEED'].idxmax()
        df.loc[max_idx, 'DELIVER'] += 1
        df.loc[df['AVAILABLE'] > 0, 'AVAILABLE'] -= 1

        
        df.loc[max_idx, 'NEED'] -= 1

df
```

Comment: I think you just really need to not use pandas for this. Definitely SQL.

Comment: I have millions of rows in reality, which is why I'm doing this in python.

Comment: That is more reason to choose sql! it is faster with indexes and so on

Comment: This is part of a bigger algorithm that is run on python, it's going to be a major change switching so that is not an option right now.

Comment: you can connect python to a postgreSQL database and run commands from your python environment. I don't see a way where your approach as is could be efficient

Comment: Again, there's a whole lot of requirements at the back end that involves working with other teams. Now I'm asking about solution on python, not a suggestion on what language to use. Thanks for suggesting though - but for this case python is needed.

Comment: check this one for some inspiration https://towardsdatascience.com/inventory-management-using-python-17cb7ddf9314

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer at all. Just some logic of how I think it could work.
Maybe you can start with something like this

```
lst_of_stores = df.STORE.unique() #getting unique store names

#create a dictionary for store name and index of where it appears
idxes = {}
for x in lst_of_stores:
  df_temp = df[df.STORE == x]
  idx = df_temp.index.values
  store_number = df_temp.STORE.values[0]
  idxes[store_number] = idx
```

Then you change values through operations, and assign them back to the dataframe using the indexes.
Good luck!